# Android: Alpha animation not starting

Tags: android, animation, button, alpha

In my menu I'm trying to implement a button that, when click, makes another button appear using an alpha animation.

```
    final Animation animAlphaUp = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animAlphaUp.setDuration(200);

    ImageButton start_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    ImageButton options_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.options_button);
    final ImageButton mute_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.options_button);

    options_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mute_button.startAnimation(animAlphaUp);
        }
    });

    mute_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
        }
    });
```

but when the options button is clicked nothing happens. The animation works, i know this because if i write this:

```
options_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       options_button.startAnimation(animAlphaUp);
    }
});
```

the animation works on the button that is clicked.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `your_button_name.startAnimation(your_animation_name);` instead.

Worked for me.